# Why is my microphone volume so quiet?

Tags: windows-10, audio, microphone

A few weeks ago I installed [Clownfish](https://clownfish-translator.com/voicechanger/) on my Huawei Matebook 13 running Windows 10 for a Zoom session, and then uninstalled it shortly after. I made sure all traces of the program were gone, including the audio drivers it installed.

Since then, my microphone has been barely picking up my voice. I'm sometimes told it has a terrible static noise louder than my voice (I'm only told this on certain platforms, I think due to more aggressive noise cancelling). Whether I'm using headphones with an in-line microphone or a headset with built-in microphone or just my computer's microphone, my voice is almost inaudible over Zoom, Discord etc. I couldn't tell you if it is any different in non-communication circumstances (eg. voice recording) as I have no idea how it originally was, but my voice sounds fine in voice recorder as far as I can tell. I've gone through all Windows settings, everything is at max volume. Images of other potentially meaningful settings:
[communication settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7FAX5.png),
[advanced settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AjOGl.png).

However, I've tried every configuration of these settings to no avail. Does anyone know what could be causing my problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since clownfish installs on a system level, try to reinstall your original audio drivers by going to device manager and selecting uninstall for your audio device. Then restart your Matebook 13 and Windows 10 will automatically reinstall your audio driver.